# How much disk space does Indexing file takes?

Tags: indexing, lucene

I am learning "Lucene in Action". It is said that in order to search the contents of files you need to index the files. I am not much clear on indexing files.

- How much file space does indexing 1 GB of documents (like doc,xls,pdb) take?
- How long it will take to index these files?
- Do we need to update the index every day?

Comment: Q1, Q2: Depends on how and how many details of these documents you index. Q3: You need to update your index whenever your documents change

Comment: @reto Okay, so we have to run the indexer every time there is a change in document rite? Will the size of index grows every time you update the document?

Comment: It usually won't, you just replace the information in the index with the updated values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q>** How much file space does indexing 1 GB of documents (like doc,xls,pdb) takes?
**A>** Your question is too vague. Documents and spreadsheets can vary from virtually nothing to tens or even hundreds of megabytes. It also depends on the analyzer you are going to use and many other factors (e.g. fields only indexed or indexed and stored, etc.). You can use [this spreadsheet](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/dev-tools/size-estimator-lucene-solr.xls) for rough estimation, plus add some extra space for merges.

**Q>** How long it will to index these files?
**A>** Again, it depends on how much content is there. Generally speaking, [indexing is fast](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2010/09/lucenes-indexing-is-fast.html). On the given link, it went as fast as 95.8 GB/hour but I assume conversion from doc/xsl will add some costs (which is irrelevant to Lucene btw).

**Q>** Do we need to update the index every day?
**A>** It is up to you. If you won't update the index, you will get the same search results. There's no magic way for new/updated content to get into index without updating.

Comment: Thank you, I am a beginner,sorry if this question is too noob to ask.

Comment: It's ok. You just need to feel yourself in answerers shoes sometimes, it helps to think if there's enough or too much details :-)